# How to add a new node and data programatically in a Firebase database and android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I just can't seem to get the logic behind adding new nodes. I've tried every combination for a simple task, How do I add driver2 with a value of eight to the root note.

I've tried a combination of push and set. I just don't seem to get it.

What goes above this line?

```
newref.child("diver2").setValue("eight");
```

[image: firebase]

Comment: "I've tried every combination for a simple task"

It really helps if you show us at least one complete combination that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is all that should be needed above that line:

```
DatabaseReference newref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

---

If that compiles and runs without errors, but doesn't end up writing to the database, you may have an outdated `google-services.json` file. You can either download the updated file from the Firebase console and add it to your app, or you can explicitly specify the database URL in your code:

```
DatabaseReference newref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your database URL").getReference();
```